# Asp.Net:Why the "click event" do not fire in my custom server control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, servercontrols

The code of my custom control is below:

```
public class Panel : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
{
    private System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel _Buttons;
    [PersistenceMode(InnerProperty)]
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel Buttons
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._Buttons == null)
                this._Buttons = new Panel();
            return this._Buttons;
        }
    }

    public Panel()
        : base("div")
    {
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(this.Buttons);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

I placed the control in the web form as below:

```
<Sunny:Panel runat=server>
    <Buttons>
        <asp:Button runat=server OnClick=Text_Click />
    </Buttons>
</Sunny:Panel>
```

The problem is that the "click event" of the button "Text_Click" do not fire.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Try to add it an ID, to see if its works

Comment: Add it an ID and also don't work. `<asp:Button runat=server ID=TestButton OnClick=Text_Click />`